# Full Calendar Customized Fields

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, customization

Hi i need to add  the customized field other than 
id, title,start,end,allday.

I have the field for Start Time and End Time in separate text box to select . Am saving the Time as String to DB, now i need to to fetch the starting Time and Ending Time

'

```
id= e.ID,
title = e.Title,
description = e.Notes,
start = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(e.StartDate),
end = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(e.EndDate),'
```

`**StartTime and EndTime**` I need to fetch this two values from DB and Shows in Popup form . I checked event Render, but its showing already available value. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for the Issue. I just added the two values 
Start-time ,End-Time next to the end Time. and called the same field in calendar.It works nice.

```
id = e.ID,
title = e.Title,
description = e.Notes,
start = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(e.StartDate),
end = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(e.EndDate),
allDay = true,
Locurl = e.Url,
```

```
startingTime = e.StartTime,
endingTime = e.EndTime
```

This is the which i used.